# Find probability of markov chain ended in state $0$.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Given transition matrix probability
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0.1&0.6&0.1&0.2\\
0.2&0.3&0.4&0.1\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with state = $\{0,1,2,3\}$.
Start from state $1$, find probability of markov chain ended in state $0$.

I have found state transition diagram. But I don't know to find probability of Markov chain ended in state $0$. What formula can be used to answer this problem? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $X_n$ of the given transition probability is eventually absorbed at $\{0,3\}$ with probability $1$. For $i=1,2$, let $p_i=\Bbb P(X_n\text{ is absorbed at }0\mid X_0=i)$. Then we can see that
$$\begin{align*}\require{cancel}
p_1&=\sum_{k=0}^3\Bbb P(X_n\text{ is absorbed at }0, X_1=k\mid X_0=1)
\\&=\sum_{k=0}^3\Bbb P(X_n\text{ is absorbed at }0\mid X_1=k\cancel{ X_0=1})\Bbb P(X_1=k\mid X_0=1)
\\&=1\cdot (0.1)+p_1\cdot (0.6)+p_2\cdot (0.1)+0\cdot (0.2).
\end{align*}$$ In the same way, $$
p_2 = (0.2)+p_1\cdot (0.3)+p_2\cdot (0.4).
$$ holds. Solving those 2 equations, we obtain
$$
p_1= \frac8{21}, \ \ \ p_2=\frac{11}{21}.
$$

Note: The vector $\pi_0=(1,p_1,p_2,0)$ of probability being absorbed at $0$ satisfies the equilibrium equation
$$
P\pi_0=\pi_0
$$where $P$ is the transition matrix, because $\pi_0  = \lim_{n\to\infty} P^n (0,1,0,0).$

Comment: So, the answer is two? 8/21 and 11/21?

 i=1,2 because it is transient states?

Comment: What you want is the probability of absorption at $0$ starting from $\color{red}1$. So the answer is $p_1=\frac8{21}$. $p_2$ is only need to solve the equation.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I will try to understand it.

Comment: I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use matrix algebra to solve for the markov chain.  I do not know if you have been taught this method.  But you can find the material in Wikepedia.

[image: solution]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to understand it